# SQL Server Database Connection Pooling?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am getting the following exception in the website which has to a large extent deal with data entry operations. It also has Indexes defined on the tables in the associated database. The database calls are made via `SQLHelper`. For e.g. `SQLHelper.ExecuteNonQuery()` etc. I cannot see anywhere that the `Close()` or `Dispose()` method of the `SQLConnection` is invoked. So I am assuming that `SQLHelper` must be taking care of it as I have also read about it on various sites. Also, to check the code in combination with `Close()` or `Dispose()` is also very tedious as `SQLHelper` is used in many places and there are many classes where business logic is defined. The exception that I am getting is:

> The record was not updated Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

For now I have tested the code with putting `GC.Collect` in the `Application_EndRequest` Method of `Global.asax` and everything as of now is working fine. But I know that it is strictly not recommend to use the same.

Any help will be GREATLY appreciated as I am stuck @ present..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure which version of your SQLHelper is, but if you can't see any connection.Close() been called then you need manually call it to make sure connection closed. Garbage collector will not close the connection for you.

**EDIT**

Also about the connection pooling it's by default enabled by .Net itself, you call connection.Close() does not mean the connection between your application to SQL Server really been closed, it's just return that connection back to connection pool and wait for others to grab. Only if after a while nobody open new connection that connection them will be physically closed, so you should not need to worry about call connection.Close() too many times, instead of that you need to call it asap to release the resource for other threads to use.

For more detail please check how Microsoft saying about connection pool: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx

**ANOTHER EDIT**
I suggest you find an updated version of SQLHelper or go ahead change SQLHelper to add Close() in it. Even if you found GC help you closed the connection but you should not use it that way, GC is not designed for release database connection but just memory, also GC.Collect() is not guaranteed it will immediately do it right away to start garbage collection.

Also you are coding web application so you need to think concurrency, what if when you calling GC.Collect() when another thread is running, will that slow down your system to other users?

It's a common sense that those limited resources (like db connection, TCP/IP port, file read/write handler etc)need to be released as soon as possible. If you are looking for an easy way to make you coding easily without even using connection.Close then you are going to a wrong direction, I understand you want simply you code and not add that line everywhere but you at least need to make sure SQLHelper doing the job to close connection.

Comment: Simon, it is very difficult to apply close method everywhere as the classes where business logic is defined are many. I also ran SQL Profiler on the db and found that the concerned connections are indeed been reset but I have no idea why are they unusable. Also I executed sproc viz sp_who and found that many connections are indeed in sleeping state and they keep on increasing with every database call. On the contrary when I placed GC.Collect() in Application_EndRequest I found that the sleeping connections are gone and the error is not coming inspite of the maximum pool size being reached.

Comment: Simon, the version of SQL Helper is as follows:public sealed class SqlHelper 
Name: Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper 
Assembly: Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data, Version=1.0.1727.33524.

Comment: Kunal, I think we might just a little bit off topic now, maybe you should just paste your code here. Btw, if you are using DataReader but you donot close the reader you might running out of connection too.